# Mongoose - Query with $gt combined with $size not working

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Here is my mongoose query (and the router):

```js
router.get('/reportsRegular', function(req,res,next){
  Question.find({reports: {$size: {$gt: 0}}, checked: false}).sort({reports: -1}).limit(20).exec(function(err,results){
    console.log(results)
    res.render('reports', {type: 'regular', user: req.user, reports: results})
})
```

and it seems there is a problem with the first find condition, when I remove the $gt to 1 instead it works, but it won't work in cases with more than one, so I need to use $gt.

Here is an example JSON document that should work but does not get found:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("6212e77aa1e98ae3282a61e6"),
  title: 'TOMATOOOOOO',
  text: '<p>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</p>',
  authorUsername: 'SweetWhite',
  dateCreated: 2022-02-21T01:14:34.901Z,
  answers: [],
  likes: [ 0 ],
  dislikes: [ 0 ],
  tag: 'Languages',
  views: [ 1, 'SweetWhite' ],
  reports: [ 'SweetWhite' ],
  checked: false,
  reportsNested: [],
  __v: 0
}
```

It should get found since the size of the reports array is bigger than zero, and the checked value is false.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need `$expr`. And change to filter as:

```
{
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      {
        "$size": "$reports"
      },
      0
    ]
  },
  checked: false
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_2nIzfULXa4)